# How to import variables in a different python file

Tags: python

I am trying to import some variables from a different python file resides in the same directory from a another python file.

**been trying this thing for hours and I still couldn't get the variables to use.**

I have two files in the same directory as below:

`const.py`

`test.py`

This is how `const.py` looks like

```
FOO = 1234
NAMESPACE = "default"
DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "deployment-test"
DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME = "banukajananathjayarathna/bitesizetroubleshooter:v1"
SERVICE_CLUSTER = "deployment-test-clusterip"
SERVICE_NODEPORT = "deployment-test-nodeport"
INGRESS_NAME = "deployment-test-ingress"
```

and this is how my `test.py` looks like:

```
import os 
from . import constant

print(constant.FOO)
```

error I am getting:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Why is it so hard to do this with Python?

Comment: `from const import FOO`

Comment: from const import *

Comment: @luigigi these are not working. Any of them are not working

Comment: then you should check your working directory

Comment: They are in the same directory. Both files are in the same directory. Why it doesn't work? Does this not work for `python 2.7.5` version?

Comment: i mean that your working directory is not always the directory in which your files are

Comment: how do you run the scripts? using an ide or directly using the shell?

Comment: I just found that this python is running in `pycharm` and in a virtuaenv.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `test.py` should look like:

```
from const import FOO

print(FOO)
```

Comment: Not working. I don't know why. Should I have to set python path or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all variable statements as they are you should do:

```py
from const import *

print(FOO)
print(NAMESPACE)
```

If you want to import variables under module name *(file name)*, you should do:

```py
import const

print(const.FOO)
print(const.NAMESPACE)
```

If you want to import variables under module name but want to access with `constant`:

```py
import const as constant

print(constant.FOO)
print(constant.NAMESPACE)
```

*The file name is the module name.*

Comment: Anything mentioned here doesn't work. Should I have to set python path or something?

Comment: If the const.py and test.py are in the same directory, there should be no problem.

Comment: They in the same folder/directory still doesn't work. Does this has anything to do with `python` version? I am using `python 2.7.5`

Comment: I don't think it would matter but you can check current directory with this: `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: I just found that this python is running in pycharm and in a `virtuaenv`