# Yet another ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
py_test
├── __init__.py
├── dir1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script1.py
└── dir2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── script2.py
```

In `script2` I want to "`import ..\script1`".

What I tried in `script2`:

1. Does not work

   ```
   from ..dir1 import script1
   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
   ```
2. Works

   ```
   import sys, os
   path2add = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir, 'dir1')))
   if (not (path2add in sys.path)) :
       sys.path.append(path2add)
   ```

**If I want to go with option 1, what is the simplest (i.e., with the least files) file/dir structure that makes it work?**
I am aware of [this](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent), but I wonder if creating that directory structure can be avoided, and still use type-1 `import`.

I am currently using [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1054293/2707864), which uses type-2 `import`.

Related:

[How to import a Python class that is in a directory above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above)

[Import a module from a directory (package) one level up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767362/import-a-module-from-a-directory-package-one-level-up/32767774)

[Getting "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" when running from Python Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088071/getting-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package-wh)

[Using importlib to dynamically import module(s) containing relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884100/using-importlib-to-dynamically-import-modules-containing-relative-imports)

[How to import variables in a different python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176229/how-to-import-variables-in-a-different-python-file)

Comment: How are you running the code? From which working directory?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - From `dir2`, within a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: You can't import relatively above the location of your main script ("script2.py" I assume). Place a main script in "py_test" which can then import and run "script2.py".

Comment: It will run ok when running via any module that imports your `py_test` package.

Comment: An import package is organized like this to be imported as a package to be used. So it does not make sense to have several entry points for execution from inside, and generally they will never work (together).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, attempting to import modules a directory up will not work ***if*** `script2.py` is your entry point.

As mentioned in [this link you included](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent):

> If the module's `__name__` does not contain any package information (e.g., it is set to `__main__`), then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top-level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

The module's `__name__` is set to `__main__` if it is the entry point, or the one that you pass to the interpreter with something like `python script2.py`.

Any python module run as such no longer has the information needed to import files from higher directories.

Therefore you have two options:

### Option 1: Keep using the workaround with `sys.path.append`

This will work how you want it to, but it is rather cumbersome.

### Option 2: Make your entry point at the top level

Assuming your package has more than one script that needs to be run, you could create a new file that imports both `script1` and `script2` and then calls the functionality you want based on a command line argument. Then you will be able to keep your current directory structure and have your relative imports work just fine, without any kind of fiddling with `sys.path`.