# Jupyter notebook ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, importerror

## Summary

I've a repository with the following structure:

```
phd-notebooks
├── notebooks
|   ├── resources
|   |   └── utils.py
|   ├── notebooks-group-1
|   |   ├── notebook1.ipynb
|   |   └── notebook2.ipynb
|   └── notebooks-group-2
|       ├── notebook1.ipynb
|       └── notebook2.ipynb
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
└── README.md
```

In my notebooks, say in `notebooks-group-1\notebook1.ipynb` for example, I want to import the module `utils.py`.

If I try `from resources import utils` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'`, if I try `from ..resources import utils` I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

I've tried to debug `notebooks-group-1\notebook1.ipynb` prompting `os.getcwd()` and I get `notebooks-group-1` as the current working directory.

I am using Visual Studio Code and a conda environment with python 3.9.13.

## What I've tried

I've tried adding an `__init.py__` file in all folders (`notebooks`, `notebooks\resources`, `notebooks\notebooks-group-1`, `notebooks\notebooks-group-2`) but I get the same errors. I don't want to use the `sys.path.append` hack or make my entry point at the top level, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691256/6583606), because when I will make the repository available I want to make running my notebooks by other people as simple as possible.

I'm aware of [this frequently cited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3), but I could not find any solution that would suit my case. Running my script using `-m` is not possible because I'm using notebooks, and even if was it would go against the requirement of making running my notebooks as simple as possible. Setting `__package__` manually is not well-suited for use in real-world code, similarly to the `sys.path.append` hack. I'm doutbful about using `setuptools` because `resources` is supposed to be a folder with a collection of utility modules for the notebooks, not a real package (it feels like an overcomplication).

How can I import the module `utils.py` in my notebooks in a pythonic way? Or it's the structure of my repository that is bad?

Answer (score 1):

This is the structure I often use for my scientific projects:

```
.
├── package1
│   ├── notebook.ipynb
│   └── __init__.py
│ 
├── package2
│   └── __init__.py
│ 
├── package3
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── process.py
│ 
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

If you want to load `process.py` in `notebook.ipynb`, add the following to `notebook.ipynb`:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('../')
from package3.process import somefunction
```